# Flutter cannot get download url firebase-storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

While trying to upload byteArray to the bucket in `firebase storage`, the file uploads to the storage but I cannot get the downloadUrl back from the file. I am getting the reference of bucket like this:

```dart
  Future<Reference> get storageRef async {
    final _bucketUrl = await bucketUrl;
    return FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: _bucketUrl).ref();
  }
```

And Uploading image like this:

```
 Future<String> uploadImageByteArray({
    @required Uint8List byteArray,
    String fileName,
  }) async {
    final name = fileName ?? DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    final _ref = await storageRef;
    final _refUrl = _ref.child("images/$name.png");
    print(_refUrl.fullPath);
    final uploadTask = _refUrl.putData(byteArray);
    final snapshot = await uploadTask;
    return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

From above code I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'NoSuchMethodError' is not a subtype of type 'Exception'.
```

It works if I get reference for the FirebaseStorage only and not the bucket like this:

```dart
 Future<Reference> get storageRef{
    return FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
  }
```

I cannot implement without using bucket reference because there can be different bucket urls depending on the tenants. What am I doing wrong?

Edit => Recent Developments:
I found out that it works if I get the downloadurl from the _refUrl itself. i.e:

```
String downloadUrl = _refUrl.getDownloadUrl();
```

It works but I can't help but wonder if it is correct implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit makes perfect sense since you have the reference to the uploaded file with _refUrl, fetching its long-lived download URL works as expected (That's how I have done it before btw). I don't have access to a project with FirebaseStorage to test this, but You can try printing `snapshot.ref.fullPath` and compare it with the fullPath of _refUrl.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Future<String> uploadImageByteArray({
    @required Uint8List byteArray,
    String fileName,
  }) async {
    final name = fileName ?? DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    final _ref = await storageRef;
    final _refUrl = _ref.child("images/$name.png");
    print(_refUrl.fullPath);
    final uploadTask = _refUrl.putData(byteArray);
    final snapshot = (await uploadTask);
    String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL(); // await
    return url;
  }
```